# Android studio Dolphin Render ui issue

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme

I updated my android studio to Dolphin. I have some ui issue:
1.Infinite cycle trying to resolve '?textAppearance': Render may not be accurate.
2.Failed to find '@android:attr/textAppearance' in current theme.

[image]

Comment: I had same. Try invalidating caches and syncing project with gradle files

Comment: Did you find a workaround OP? Invalidating cache / syncing didn't work for me.

Comment: I see this problem as well.  The funny thing is that the layout actually displays for about 1 second and then disappears.  The Component tree is still there.  Same two errors as well.  Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

This happens for a reason: There may indeed be styles missing.
`Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge` & `Widget.MaterialComponents`

For example, when applying `android:theme` in XML:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FloatingActionButton"
```

But the referenced material style does not define any `@android:attr/textAppearance`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FloatingActionButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
</style>
```

---

The style attribute might be missing somewhere else, than where the render error occurs.
When `FragmentContainerView` won't render, see `app:startDestination` and its `tools:layout`.
Searching for string `android:theme` in directory `res/layout` should turn up all the references.